# Alternatives for bind an event to a property

Tags: c#, mvvm, win-universal-app, commandbinding, event-binding

I've a list box but if I click on an item, I must see the details of that item. I've made this code where I try to bind the `SelectionChanged` event to a property whit type `RelayCommand` and mode is two way.

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVillage, Mode=TwoWay}" 
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource lstidflt}" 
         SelectionChanged="{Binding SelectedVillageChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource weatheritemdt}" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding VillageList}" />
```

This doesn't work of course because you can't bind an event to a property or a property to a method and vice versa. You can only bind a property to a property. So the question is now are there alternatives to bind a `SelectionChanged` event to a property?

I use C# in a Windows universal 10 application with the MVVM light architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just let the binding of the SelectedItem property

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding VillageList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVillage, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

And do the job in the setter

```
public class VillageViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Village> VillageList { get; set; } 

    private Village selectedItem;
    public Village SelectedItem
    {
        get { return selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedItem == value)
                return;
            selectedItem = value;
            // Do logic on selection change.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I do (in WPF) is bind the selected item to a full property then raise the event in the set part. It will look something like this;

```
private Village _SelectedVillage;
public Village SelectedVillage{
get {return _SelectedVillage;}
set {
    _SelectedVillage = value;
    RaiseEvent myEvent();
}
}
```

You can also raise the relaycommand or check for a trigger in xaml. If you go with the property, look at dependency property if it's available in win 10 universal.